# Using Spring ApplicationContext getBeansOfType does not returns all beans if different jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, spring-bean

I have two classes (First and Second) implementing the same interface. Both have the `@Component` annotation and `@ComponentScan` is working fine.

But when I am trying to call `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyInterface.class)`, only one bean is returned. If I try `applicationContext.getBean(SecondClass.class)`, it works (although is not a proxy bean).

What I do not understand is: this behavior does not happen if both Components are in the same .war, but if I put one of them in a jar (maven dependency) the problem happens.

What might be the my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be a classloading issue. Are you sure MyInterface.class only exists in the maven dependency? If you have more than one copy of the interface loaded, via different classloaders, java will not consider them the same interface (class)

Comment: This interface is in a common library (another jar), that way both (war and jar) can implement the same interface. But in my maven dependency, that common jar is declared as provided, except for the .war. Do you think this could be a problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RalphRitoch, I think you are completely right! After a refactoring, I did all the configuration again and it worked. Sorry for any trouble, there is nothing wrong with `SpringBoot @Configuration` or `@ComponentScan` between jars. This issue can be closed.